# How to number HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible, and if so how? To number HTML tags, for example if someone pushes a button which calls a javascript method, the method can identify which button was pushed by its number. I then want to change the  button's image, by putting all the image file names in an array so its easy to change the image using 1 line of JavaScript.

Comment: add custom attribute with it let say SNo

Comment: custome attribute, ill check it out cheers

Comment: are custome attributes HTML 5 only? @ShehzadBilal

Comment: cool looks like the solution. If you write this as an answer Ill mark it as correct. Cheers @ShehzadBilal

Comment: Yes, of course they are HTML 5 only, at least if you want to write fully valid HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Custom Attributes for this:

```
<input type="button" data-sno="1">
```

Answer (score 4):

In HTML5 you can use [custom attributes](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml), their names have to start with "data-".

```
<input type="button" data-index="1" />
```

Without relying on that, you can add a class name that contains the number, e.g.

```
<input type="button" class="index-1" />
```

Another way would be to use [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) to attach event listeners via Javascript as closures that keep a reference to the index number of the button:

```
$('.buttonclass').each(function(index, button){
    button.click(function(){
        // event handling code that uses the index variable
    })
});
```

(the above code uses jQuery, which is not strictly necessary but makes things easier)